# {Leetcode: Palindrome number}runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, palindrome

Runtime error for leetcode question: check palindrome number

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        //to figure v.size() or x
        int k=10;
        int j=1;
        bool b=true;
        while(x/k!=0){
            j++;
            k=k*10;
        }
        
        //to fill vector
        vector<int> v;
        for(int i=0; i<j; i++){
            v[i]=x%10;
            x=x/10;
        }
        
        //to chk palindrome
        for(int l=0; l<j; l++){
            if(v[l]!=v[j-l]){
                b=false;//how to keep the same value outside the loop as well
                //return false;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    return b;
    }
};
```

1. I'm getting this error:

> ```
> Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9
> ```

2. it's only showing true, never false. i think its because "`b`" doesn't get saved as false outside the loop, how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `vector<int> v`, and its size == 0;

Then you try to access `v[i]`, this throws [std::out_of_range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).

See correct code here,

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        //to figure v.size() or x
        int k=10;
        int j=1;
        bool b=true;
        while(x/k!=0){
            j++;
            k=k*10;
        }

        //to fill vector
        vector<int> v(j);
        for(int i=0; i<j; i++){
            v[i]=x%10;
            x=x/10;
        }

        //to chk palindrome
        for(int l=0; l<j; l++){
            if(v[l]!=v[j-1-l]){
                b=false;//how to keep the same value outside the loop as well
                //return false;
            }
            else{
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
};
```

clean version ^,^ :

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    bool isPalindrome(int x) {
        auto v = to_string(x);

        //to chk palindrome
        return equal(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), v.begin(), v.end());
    }
};
```

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua Leetcode enables [UBSan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#available-checks) , `Array subscript out of bounds, where the bounds can be statically determined`. If you use a normal compiler without UBSan enabled, you get `out_of_range`